# NSIS code if-else to stack operation

Tags: nsis

I always get confused when it comes to nsis stack operation. Now I'm writing a small piece of code for trimming trailing space from a string.

> Input:
>
> > C:\Program Files (x86)\COMPANY\ or C:\Program Files (x86)\COMPANY
>
> Output:
>
> > C:\Program Files (x86)\COMPANY

**Working code - with normal if-else**

```
!define TrimPath '!insertmacro "_TrimPath"'
!macro _TrimPath _FOLDERPATH

    StrCpy $0 `${_FOLDERPATH}` 1 -1
    ${If} $0 == "\"
        StrCpy $1 `${_FOLDERPATH}` -1
        StrCpy `${_FOLDERPATH}` $1
    ${EndIf}
    
!macroend
```

**Wrong code - with stack operation**

```
!define TrimPath '!insertmacro "_TrimPath"'
!macro _TrimPath _FOLDERPATH

    Exch $0
    
    StrCpy $2 $0 1 -1
    StrCmp $2 "\" +2 +1
        StrCpy $1 $0 -1
    StrCpy $1 $0
    
    Pop $0
    Exch $1

!macroend
```

Can anyone correct me and point me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to use a macro as a function. Some comments/questions/hints:

- Why are you using `Exch` which swaps the value in the top of the stack instead of using `_FOLDERPATH` ?
- Are you pushing the parameter in the stack before calling the macro? Something like:

> push $path
>
> ${Trimpath}

- `Pop $0` restores the value of $0 but then you call Exch $1 which will swap the value in top of the stack (unknow value, maybe the stack is empty) with $1. Why?? If you want to save the result in the stack, just `push $1`.

Comment: Thanks, push $1 was my answer.